# Hf-tikz anh tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some problems with these packages; if anyone of you could help me I would really appreciate.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,%amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}% <-----------------------
\usetheme{dresden}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}% 
\listfiles
\tikzset{set fill color=red!30,set border color=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\textcolor{white}{Overeducation and the GPG}}
Mincer wage equation: 
\begin{equation*}\notag
\ln{W_i}={{X_i}^{'}}\beta+\gamma{Overeducation}+\epsilon_i
\end{equation*}
Oaxaca-Blinder decomposition:
\begin{align*}
z+t&=\tikzmarkin<2>{a}{vshade}[x+y]\tikzmarkend{a}{vshade}\\ 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [->](-2,0) -- (2,0);
\filldraw [black] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {May 20,2014};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}`
```

In the first slide, I do not understand why the option 'shade' does not work..

In the second slide, instead, I would like to write a number over the line , which should be some 0 before the date and some 1 after. I would like the number to shift from left to right transforming from 0 to 1..

Does anyone know how I could do it? Thanks a lot! :)
Giulia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors. `Dresden` instead of `dresden`, a `%` before `amsfonts` and `\tikzmarkin` takes only one argument.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}% <-----------------------
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[beamer,customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}% 
\listfiles
\tikzset{set fill color=red!30,set border color=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\textcolor{white}{Overeducation and the GPG}}
Mincer wage equation: 
\begin{equation*}\notag
\ln{W_i}={{X_i}^{'}}\beta+\gamma{Overeducation}+\epsilon_i
\end{equation*}
Oaxaca-Blinder decomposition:
\begin{align*}
 z+t&=\tikzmarkin<2>[top color=white, bottom color=blue!20]{a}
[x+y]\tikzmarkend{a}\\ 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (date) {May 20,2014};
\draw[->] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1mm]date.north west) --
([xshift=1cm,yshift=1mm]date.north east) coordinate[midway] (X);
\filldraw [black] (X) circle (2pt)  node[above]{some number};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the problem was not present without the option 'vshade'.. I mean, I obtained the same as you obtained by keeping away 'vshade' from the \tikmarzin.. the point is that I was wonderind why tho option 'shade' and writing 'vshade' as suggested in the guide of the package does not work and gives me an error..

Comment: @giulia I think you are mistaken in your interpretation what `vshade` in `\tikzmarkin[top color=white, bottom color=blue!20]{vshade}
 x+y=400
\tikzmarkend{vshade}` of the example does. `vshade` is just a name of a label, which you could also call `cutefurryrodent`, say. In particular, `\tikzmarkin` has one optional and one mandatory arguments, but you were trying to add another mandatory argument. So you can keep either `a` or `vshade`, but not both.

Comment: Ahh ok I understand what you mean, thanks a lot. however, even if I keep only 'vshade' as mandatory argument and not 'a' ,the shadings that should appear according to the example do not appear in my case.. maybe I am making some mistakes.. however, it was just a curiosity :)  Do you know the package I need to do the second request? it would be fantastic.. thanks however, your help was really appreciated :)

Comment: @giulia The shading is controlled by the optional argument `[top color=white, bottom color=blue!20]`, so I added that. I also added a proposal for the line. If you want it shorter, just adjust the `xshift` directives, i.e. make them smaller.

Comment: God yees obviouslyyyy it was the one in the square bracketss :o sorry for that.. and thanks againnn!

Comment: Sorry I am new and I didn't know how the forum worked.. thanks again :)